# Set NoData values to cells with a value and vice versa?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am working on a ModelBuilder model that calculates natural habitat based on different attributes such as proximity to water, landcovers, elevation (all raster data). I also want to take into account "human disturbance" - i.e. exclude areas that are too close to a developed area.

To do that, I took the landcover raster, used the Con tool to assign all "developed" cells value of 1 and a NoData value to all other cells. Then, I used the Euclidean Distance tool to create a "buffer" around those "developed" cells. So, now I have a raster that has cells with regular values in the "buffered" zone around developed areas and NoData further from developed areas and I need the exact opposite - NoData around the developed areas and regular values further from them.

[image: picture]

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with the [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclass-by-individual-values.htm) tool.

Here I have created a raster same as your example above - top two cells have a value of `1`, the bottom two are `NULL` (or `NoData`).  The `1` coloured black, and I have coloured the `NoData` with "Sahara Sand" so it shows in the screenshot.

In the Reclassify tool I literally just reverse the values by typing in `NoData` next to the `1`, and a `1` next to the `NoData`.

[image]

And the result - the raster is reversed.  The `1` coloured black, and the `NoData` with "Sahara Sand".

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you! Just for clarity, this is how to enter range of values:

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2agMO.png)